# Is this a bad [code-design]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I recently stumbled on a question with the [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design) tag.  I thought it was off-topic.  A brief scan of the [159 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design) with this tag reveals a majority of opinion-based questions (in my opinion, of course.)

The answer to [Can I ask design-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252139/can-i-ask-design-related-questions-on-stack-overflow) is:

> In general - no. Such questions are beyond the scope of Stack Overflow

The [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design) tag has no usage guidance.  Some of the questions are also tagged with [design-principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-principles) ([274 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-principles), previous [synonym-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382605/merge-synonymize-principles-and-design-principles-with-patterns), usage guidance "ideas that guide developers toward certain goals in software design.") which would seem to have a similar conclusion.

Which brings me to [software-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-design) with [1566 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-design) which, if it's on topic, would be a good synonym target for [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design).  It was [previously mentioned here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397853/lets-improve-our-software-design) with a comment suggesting burnination.

Its guidance:

> the activity of deciding what ... [is] required in order to create an effective piece of software.

This is a key part of the [Systems Development Life Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) which is the primary context of [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

**Proposal**

At a minimum I would think [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design) and [design-principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-principles) should be synonyms for [software-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-design).

More importantly, the tag wiki for these design-related tags should discourage (if not outright prohibit) their future use.

At the maximum, the tags should be removed and the off-topic/opinion-based questions closed.

**Are the tags causing active harm?**

The [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design) tag has only been used 10 times in the last year. However, [software-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-design) and [design-principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-principles) are actively attracting off-topic questions on a regular basis.

My evaluation of the burnination criteria, applied in general to all three of the above tags:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Broadly, it describes the context. However, it is so broad that it is ambiguous.  It attracts opinion-based questions on [ethics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63462687/is-this-ethical-to-create-a-bot-software-that-automatically-compute-data-daily), [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63434690/should-we-prefer-composition-over-inheritance-when-we-can-only-use-default-const), [starting from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382203/start-a-huge-application-from-scratch-in-linux-environment), [thesis advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367487/bachelor-thesis-advice-architecure-patterns-systems-architecture), [tool recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488473/libgdx-software-design), and more.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

As cited above, "In general - no."

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No.  On-topic questions would have to be related to a specific design principle, with code.  "How do I apply the X design to this code" gains no information with a design-related tag.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Broadly, yes.  But the common context of code design/software design/design principles is not an appropriate context for questions on *this* site.

Comment: Didn't we create two entire new sites for whiteboard style and code critique questions, because they didn't mesh well with practical problems unique to software engineering?

Comment: Related: [We are out of new \[design\]s](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376346/4642212); seems very similar to some old, [undesirable tags like \[coding-practices\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93669/289905).

Comment: On the topic of [tag:design-principles], we have [tag:solid-principles], [tag:dry], [tag:yagni], etc. Can there even be an abstract on-topic question that can be tagged with [tag:design-principles] that *is not* about a specific principle?

Comment: Just for the sake of it, I also have a similar burninate-request still open about [code-cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383165/time-to-cleanup-code-cleanup), which is in the same sense a meta tag. And could with the same reasoning be cleaned up

Comment: Bad_code_design?!

Comment: I haven't heard the term "code design" before but it sounds potentially narrower than "software design", in being restricted to just design considerations expressed in code. (As opposed to things like, calling external services, databases, broader software architecture considerations etc.)

Comment: If you don't like some tags, that doesn't mean they must be removed

Comment: @Gigino Is "OP doesn't like this tag" really the only thing you got from this Meta question?

Comment: Toss `theory` ([1671 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/theory)) into the discussion as well. I actually like that tag (and the others) but don't like many of the questions there...

Comment: Is there some way to make the tag only usable in conjunction with some more specific tag?  It seems incredibly useful for sorting and searching questions.  In general I would suggest that approach for any "meta" tag that provides value, but doesn't by itself qualify a question to be on SO (or whatever the SE site may be).  Of course, I have no idea what `burninate` means, so maybe that is the current suggestion.

Comment: @DylanYoung https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag

Comment: @DylanYoung [Tag info should also be useful reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) And if not, it should be fixed do that it is.

Comment: @Braiam what are the two new sites for whiteboard style and code critique questions you mentioned?

Comment: @typo one of them is already mentioned in the question.

Comment: I understand the premise.  If I read the reasoning correctly I believe it's fully addressed by the concept of "subordinate tags" which would be required them to be accompanied by other non-subordinate tags and hence they would never "stand alone".  Not my software though, lol.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, not much more

Comment: @DylanYoung explicitly there should not be any kind of hierarchy on tags. They are meant to be flat.

Comment: @Braiam I never suggested anything of the sort, lol.  You're absolutely correct that a hierarchy of tags would be a complete mess.  What isn't a mess is providing users with the data they need to make meaningful searches :)   But like I said, it's not my software and I generally don't bikeshed with people more interested in their opinions than the quality of their software.  However, if devs show interest, I'd be happy to discuss further.

Answer (score 19):

I object to [design-principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-principles) being a synonym for [software-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-design), because it is potentially more general. It can involve principles from engineering-in-general, or other fields of engineering. Or it can regard hardware-software-codesign. If that's not the case - please make an argument to that effect. Also, "design" and "design-principles" are similar, but not identical - like [idioms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idioms) and [idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idiomatic) which are  justifiably separate.

So I would split the suggestion regarding [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design) from the suggestion regarding [design-principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-principles). It seems the first suggestion has merit.

Comment: In the context of [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and the [software engineering stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) `design-principles` must be applicable to software engineering and not engineering in general.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues: Not really. A question may involve programming, but also a system in which the hardware was designed according to some (non-software) principle.

Comment: @einpoklum How such hardware was designed is irrelevant to the question because hardware topics are off-topic here.

Comment: @TylerH exactly. That was my point.

Comment: @einpoklum The question may very well involve hardware, as they often involve contacting external systems. The system design of such external system, however good or bad, is not a topic of discussion in here. The software system that interacts with that external system is.

Comment: @TylerH: Maybe it is and maybe it isn't. I wouldn't presume to make a sweeping call about this "en passant" when considering the "code-design" tag.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues: See my answer to TylerH. Maybe so, maybe no.

Comment: For me it seems like a very reasonable tag in questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040118/how-to-avoid-global-variables-in-fortran-90-or-higher)

Comment: `design-principles` also applies to UX design which is very closely related to software engineering. Having that as a tag would be extremely unclear.

Comment: @CWSites: So please open a different burninate/mass-retag post about it.

Comment: @einpoklum, I don't want to create a whole other conversation, just giving some feedback to the answers posted here

Answer (score 9):

I don't see why any of these three tags is actually on-topic to the site.

- [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design) calls after primarily opinion-based questions, asking for what coding-style is better than the other and one could also think it should mean to "designing code" in the way of "developing code".
- [design-principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-principles) is beside being about off-topic design choices very broad and unclear.

  If your question is focusing a specific principle then you should be able to identify the design-principle directly and everyone knows which principle you mean. Adding [design-principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-principles) seems redundant.

  With that loose focus, I think it also provides the space to post opinion-based questions similar to [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design).
- [software-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-design) tend like [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design) to be an object of opinion-focused questions to chose what preferred style or design to apply.

  Also I think it has a very decent touch of ambiguity the same as [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design). It could stand for stylistic choices at the software development or creating software in general.

  In both cases, it gives a reason to be burninated.

#### Conclusion:

The tags might be on-topic on other sites of the network but I think not so on Stack Overflow. Questions about stylistic choices (designs) and preferred styles are off-topic to the site. Beside that, [software-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-design) is too broad and ambiguous and [design-principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-principles) is broad and redundant.

My personal feeling:

**Burninate all three tags**.